# how can we get param from yaml?

Tags: ros, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

node_name1:
param_name1: value
param_name2: value

node_name2:
param_name1: value
param_name2: value

This is a yaml file,but how can we get param from yaml in our .cpp files?
.getParam doesnot work.
THANK YOU!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267865/how-can-we--get-param-from-yaml?/) by [neil](https://answers.ros.org/users/31418/neil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your launch file, put

---

Originally posted by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) with karma: 127 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-02**:
This will load it into the `Parameter Server` and make the params available to your node. Now you can use `getParam()` to access those set params.

**Comment by [neil](https://answers.ros.org/users/31418/neil/) on 2017-08-02**:
Thank you very much! I have solved the problems.I misunderstood the Parameter Server.Now I understand it . getParam() get params from Paramter Server ,no mater the params come from launch file or yaml file. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server) for cpp programming or [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server) for python.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neil](https://answers.ros.org/users/31418/neil/) on 2017-08-02**:
Thank you very much! I have solved the problems.I misunderstood the Parameter Server.Now I understand it . getParam() get params from Paramter Server ,no mater the params come from launch file or yaml file. thank you again.
ROS answer is wonderful.